# AWS MongoDB cluster Provisioning through Ansible

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, mongodb-replica-set

We are deploying mongodb cluster through ansible on AWS EC2 instance.
Once a DB instance is provisioned, we give it corresponding tag for Primary / Secondary. We have 3 nodes - 1 for Primary and 2 for secondary.

While running the ansible scripts for the first time, we are choosing the primary instance by Tag type, initiating it and adding secondary nodes to it

```
rs.initiate()
rs.add(secodnaryHost1)
rs.add(secondaryHost2)
```

This works fine.

However at times, when one of the secondary becomes the primary, our instance Tag type - primary and mongoDB - primary are not the same.
At such a scenario, if we run our ansible scripts, they fail because the primary tag type (which is now a secondary) can't run above commands.

What are the best ways to handles such mismatch?

Comment: It isn't helpful to use Tags to indicate which node is the primary and which are secondary, because (as you have noticed) when the existing primary node goes offline then a different node will be [elected](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/) to take the role of primary.  Is there any special reason why your Ansible script needs to know which node is the primary?

Answer (score 2):

You should read [the current status](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/#dbcmd.replSetGetStatus) and in a template or through command line define appropriate settings.
Please search in [available ansible-galaxy roles](https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles?page=1&page_size=10&autocomplete=mongodb).

PS:

Example template [repset_init.j2](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/mongodb/roles/mongod/templates/repset_init.j2) and its provision

```
- name: Create the file to initialize the mongod replica set
  template: src=repset_init.j2 dest=/tmp/repset_init.js

- name: Pause for a while
  pause: seconds=20

- name: Initialize the replication set
  shell: /usr/bin/mongo --port "{{ mongod_port }}" /tmp/repset_init.js
```